# Are there any softwares that can integrate with desktop sims that accurately simulate third party EFIS retrofits?

Tags: flight-instruments, display

So, are there any softwares out there that can integrate into desktop simulators, that can accurately emulate third party EFIS instruments for example, Dynon EFIS or Aspen Avionics Evolution?

Comment: If I remember right, [XPlane has a pretty good G1000](https://x-plane.com/manuals/G1000_Manual.pdf).

Comment: @RonBeyer yep, but let's face it, a cessna 172 with G1000 is gonna cost ya a quarter million dollars. I don't have that kind of money, and I want to retrofit. I do indeed have xplane and can testify that the G1000 is an amazingly accurate recreation.